# Some checkboxes won't work (HTML,PHP)

Tags: php, android, html

On a page I have about 40 checkboxes. Only the last of them will work on my android-browser. On my PC (Internet explorer, chrome, Firefox) everything works fine.

See here:
stufentheorie.de / tonart-bestimmen.html

**Here is the code:**

```
   <form action='' method='post' role='form'>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3>Dur-Akkorde</h3>

 <?
$i = "0";
foreach ($toene as $ton)
{
    $wert = $ton . " " . $geschlecht[0];
    $ch = '';
    if (is_array($input_chord) == true)
    {
        if (in_array($wert, $input_chord))
        {
            $ch = " checked=\"checked\"";
        }
    }
    echo "<span style=\"width:120px;display:block;float:left;\"><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"akkord[".$wert."]\" value=\"" . $wert . "\"" . $ch . "> " . $wert . " </span>";
    $i ++;
    if ($i % 6 == 0)
    {
        echo "";
    }


}

?>

</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
<br style="clear:left;" />
<h3>Moll-Akkorde</h3>



 <?
$i = "0";
foreach ($toene as $ton)
{
    $wert = $ton . " " . $geschlecht[1];
    $ch = '';
    if (is_array($input_chord) == true)
    {
        if (in_array($wert, $input_chord))
        {
            $ch = " checked=\"checked\"";
        }
    }
    echo "<span style=\"width:120px;display:block;float:left;\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"akkord[".$wert."]\" value=\"" . $wert . "\"" . $ch . "> " . $wert . " </span> ";
    $i ++;
    if ($i % 5 == 0)
    {
        echo "";
    }


}

?> 
</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
<br style="clear:left;" />
<h3>Verminderte Akkorde</h3>



 <?
$i = "0";
foreach ($toene as $ton)
{
    $wert = $ton . " " . $geschlecht[2];
    $ch = '';
    if (is_array($input_chord) == true)
    {
        if (in_array($wert, $input_chord))
        {
            $ch = " checked=\"checked\"";
        }
    }
    echo "<span style=\"width:120px;display:block;float:left;\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"akkord[".$wert."]\" value=\"" . $wert . "\"" . $ch . "> " . $wert . " </span> ";
    $i ++;
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
    {
        echo "";
    }


}

?>
</div></div>

<br /> <br />

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><input type='submit' class='btn btn-block btn-lg btn-theme' value='Tonart bestimmen'/></div></form>
```

Why does the browser only work with the last checkboxes "verminderte Akkorde"?

The code for all the checkboxes is exactly the same.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please explain "work" in developer terms. What exactly happens, or doesn't happen ?

Comment: You can't select the first checkboxes. Only the last are selectable.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're creating a large amount of them, but all with the same name - `akkord[]`. Try putting something in the `[]` array part to make the name of each checkbox different.

Comment: can you please reformat your code so that it doesn't contain that `>` stitch?

Comment: Changed it to 
`<span style=\"width:120px;display:block;float:left;\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"akkord[".$wert."]\" value=\"" . $wert . "\"" . $ch . "> " . $wert . " </span> ";` still it doesn't work.

Comment: reformated the code.

Comment: Are there any errors when error reporting is set to catch and display? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Also look at your HTML source, that can/will reveal certain things that are passing through or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams it problem with positions

What I did is removed `"width:120px;display:block;float:left;` and made each span with `col-md-4`

like

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <span style=""><input type="checkbox" name="akkord[]" value="C dur"> C 
     dur </span>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <span style=""><input type="checkbox" name="akkord[]" value="Cis dur"> 
     Cis dur </span>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <span style=""><input type="checkbox" name="akkord[]" value="Des 
       dur"> Des dur </span>
</div>
</div>
```

OR else

simply remove style properties on span and add responsive classes to fix width and position